# Ошибка сертификата при открытии сайта с уcтройства Android

Tags: ssl, iis, letsencrypt, windows-server-2012

Проблема следующая:
Есть сайт, развернут на Windows Server 2012 R2. IIS 8, если не ошибаюсь.
Получил сертификат от lets encrypt, который X3.

Везде корректно работает, кроме устройств андроид. Конкретно у меня Android 6 и все равно ругается на сертификат.

Сначала думал, что проблема в использовании SNI. Сейчас развернул на отдельной машине, где только этот сайт и отключил SNI. Тем не менее, с андроид устройства есть проблемы с сертификатом.

Сайт доступен по адресу https://b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net/

Comment: Какой браузер ругается?

Comment: Google Chrome 50.0.2661.89

Comment: Даты верные на телефоне и время?

Comment: Да, все верное. Тоже об этом подумал сначала.

Comment: Так может у кого-нибудь корректно открывается?

Comment: Протестируйте сайт с помощью Qualys SSL Labs Test:https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net&latest

он помимо оценки выдает еще и рекомендации для улучшения работы сервера

Comment: Искреннее спасибо за ответ! Проблему решил неделю назад, забыл сюда отписать. Суть в том, что на сервере были прописаны другие сертификаты и сертификационные центры, которые являлись не достоверными. И мобильные браузеры пытались их использовать, несмотря на то, что они не имеют отношение к этому сайту. Удалил их из системы и все стало корректно работать.

Comment: К сожалению, сайт по ссылке больше недоступен((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за предложенные варианты и комментарии.

Проблема была в следующем: на сервере были прописаны другие сертификаты и сертификационные центры, которые являлись не достоверными. И мобильные браузеры пытались их использовать, несмотря на то, что они не имеют отношение к этому сайту.

Удалил их из системы и все стало корректно работать.

Удалил, используя утилиту certmgr.msc
[image: Директории, в которых удалил все лишнее]

Удалял субъективно, то есть все, что не знал и не видел на чистой машине)

Answer (score 3):

от проекта *letsencrypt* вы получаете (в числе прочих) примерно такие файлы:

- cert.pem — ваш сертификат
- chain.pem — сертификат удостоверяющего центра
- fullchain.pem — оба сертификата в одном файле

ошибка, которую показывает *openssl* по поводу сертификата, который предоставляет ваш сервер:

```
$ :| openssl s_client -connect b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net:443 > /dev/null
depth=0 CN = b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
DONE
```

свидетельствует о том, что в качестве сертификата вы явно указали `cert.pem` — файл, в котором содержится только ваш сертификат, без сертификата удостоверяющего центра.

выхода как минимум два:

- либо использовать файл `fullchain.pem` вместо используемого сейчас `cert.pem`
- либо указать вашему http-серверу использовать **также** и файл `chain.pem` как сертификат удостоверяющего центра. если, конечно, ваш http-сервер поддерживает такую возможность.

---

после такой переконфигурации *openssl* не будет показывать той ошибки, что присутствует сейчас:

```
$ :| openssl s_client -connect b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net:443 > /dev/null
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = b2bfamily.trafficmanager.net
verify return:1
DONE
```

---

отсутствие же ошибки в некоторых браузерах, насколько я понимаю, вызвано тем, что у них уже прописан сертификат удостоверяющего центра, используемого проектом *letsencrypt*.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Проблему решил неделю назад, забыл сюда отписать. Суть в том, что на сервере были прописаны другие сертификаты и сертификационные центры, которые являлись не достоверными. И мобильные браузеры пытались их использовать, несмотря на то, что они не имеют отношение к этому сайту. Удалил их из системы и все стало корректно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать fullchain сертификат.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?